# Inconsistent sizes of release APKs

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I'm getting different APK sizes (by up to 15%) when I generate signed APKs in Android Studio 4.1.2. I generate one APK and it's like 8100 KB, and then immediately I generate it again without changing anything and it's 7600 KB. This is happening repeatedly and I've never noticed it before.

When I rename the APKs to zip and open them with 7zip, the larger one takes a second to open (the smaller one opens immediately) and all the file and directory sizes are the same between two files. The only difference is the the bigger file has a bunch of zero size files that correspond to the name of the archive (for example if I renamed app-release-1.apk to app-release-1.zip, these files will be named app-release-1) while the smaller file has only one of these files.

I'm attaching a screenshot of this, notice that the physical size is different even though other sizes are the same. And the bunch of zero length files.

[image]

Obviously I want to know why is this happening, it's very strange.

Comment: AS 4.1.2 is outdated, does it happen in 4.2?

Comment: It's been outdated by a few weeks and I'm not going to upgrade until I get to the bottom of this.

Comment: You can do parallel installation if you're against an update. Still my point stands, see if this issue happens on newest version or you might be losing time fighting with old bug.

Comment: Oh right, I didn't know I can have multiple versions. I'll try it and see.